Visibility on viewport
Objects even though appear in scene collection, they are not visible in the viewport

It appears that you disabled the visibility of the whole collection, you can change it in the outliner, which also shows that they are not visible, because the collection is greyed out.
Click the eye of the collection, to see them again.
